# Safari beforeunload Fetch API

Tags: javascript, safari, onbeforeunload

I'm calling the fetch API in `beforeunload`:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
    Livewire.emitTo('partials.game-queue-component', 'leave');
});
```

The `Livewire.emitTo` performs a fetch request.

This works perfectly in Chrome, but Safari gives me the following error:

> Fetch API cannot load http://dio-ccg.test/livewire/message/partials.game-queue-component due to access control checks.

How do I get the Fetch API to work inside `beforeunload` in Safari?